# Configuring XPRESS solver in PuLP, path not found

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp, xpress-optimizer

I'm working with PuLP 1.6 and had the FICO XPRESS solver installed already before installing PuLP.

When I run `pulp.pulpTestAll()` it doesn't show the XPRESS solver as unavailable but instead the test fails with the message:

`The system cannot find the path specified. 
pulp.constants.PulpError: Tests Failed`

How can I configure a PuLP solver, specifically the path? The XPRESS bin folder is in my path currently.

Edit: I have found the `pulp.cfg.win`and tried enter my path in some different ways (e.g. `XpressPath = C:\xpressmp\bin\optimizer.exe`, but it didn't change the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a solution on how to get the XPRESS interface working in PuLP (I also posted an issue to GitHub, but we couldn't find a solution either (https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/issues/143)).

However, I realized that XPRESS itself offers a Python package within their newer versions. I was not aware of this in the beginning and ended up using the their package, which works just fine and is similar to PuLP. Maybe this can help someone.